# How to create clean Docker Container from image?

Tags: docker

I am using Docker v. 18.03.1-ce on Windows 10.

I created a new docker container(db server): *docker run –p 2638:2638 –name db sybase12*

Updated a record in a table, committed and closed connection to the db server.

Deleted the db container:
*docker stop db* and then *docker rm –f db*

Created a new container:  *docker run –p 2638:2638 –name db1 sybase12*

Connected to the db1 server and ran select statement on the previously updated record. It returned the updated record instead of initial one.

Per the Docker documentation, it is read that the image is immutable:

> The major difference between a container and an image is the top
>   writable layer. All writes to the container that add new or modify
>   existing data are stored in this writable layer. When the container is
>   deleted, the writable layer is also deleted. **The underlying image
>   remains unchanged**

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers

I expect a clean docker container every time I start it per the Docker documentation.

What am I missing here?

What should I do to start a clean Docker container?

Comment: i've always used docker-compose down to blow away my docker instance, but i'm no docker expert

Comment: I don't think that this will answer your question, but try changing `docker rm –f db` to `docker rm –fv db`.  The extra 'v' blows away any volumes that may be persisting data.  However, (1) I don't know there are any volumes associated with the image; and (2) if there are shouldn't you get a fresh set of volumes every time - so no persistence.  Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can educate us.  Even if it is not the answer, it can't hurt, and it will remove one possible answer.

Comment: How are you building the `sybase12` image? Can you share the `Dockerfile`? I'm curious what base image you're using and whether that image mounts a volume.

Comment: I built the Sybase image with dockerfile file. During the creation of the image, the db, Sybase binaries and a powershell script are copied and compressed into the image. Upon starting the docker container, the powershell script starts the db process. For this container I do not map any volumes.